# sudo cd into a directory with Fabric

Tags: python, sudo, fabric

I am new to Fabric and I am trying to cd into a directory I don't have permission to, so I'm using `sudo`.  (The permissions on the directory are drwx------, i.e., 700)

I am using Fabric 0.9.7.

I tried this:

```
from fabric.api import run, env
from fabric.context_managers import cd

env.hosts = [ '1.2.3.4' ]
env.user = 'username'

def test():
       run('sudo cd /my/dir')
              run('ls')
```

But this gives me "sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo" which is understandable.  I've also tried this:

snip:

```
def test():
        with cd('/my/dir'):
                run('ls')
```

But this returns "permission denied", again understandable.

In a nutshell, how do I "`sudo cd`" within Fabric?

Answer (score 4):

As others have explained, `cd` is a shell builtin in Linux, but `sudo` only works with executables, so `sudo cd` cannot work.

Therefore even using `with c.cd()` and `sudo()` with latest Fabric does not work, this task:

```py
@task
def pwd(c):
    with c.cd('/tmp'):
        c.sudo('pwd')
```

results in the following error:

```sh
sudo: cd: command not found
```

The arguably unattractive workaround is to launch a new shell with `sudo()` for the command and manually prefix it with `cd`:

```py
@task
def pwd(c):
    c.sudo('sh -c "cd /tmp && pwd"')
```

See [this Invoke issue](https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke/issues/687).

Answer (score 3):

Is there any reason you're not just using [`sudo()`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.sudo)? It may work around the issue you're having.

If you're using a version of Fabric before 1.0, you'll need to explicitly [tell it to create a TTY](http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.0/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.sudo):

```
sudo("ls", pty=True)
```

Otherwise, you may need to edit your sudoers file and remove or comment out this line:

```
Defaults    requiretty
```

Should be:

```
#Defaults    requiretty
```

Also, it may be more annoying, but if `with cd(...)` causes problems, you can always pass the path as an argument to `ls`:

```
sudo("ls /my/dir")
```

Comment: I get "NameError: global name 'sudo' is not defined" when I did def test(): sudo("ls", pty=True) - maybe the syntax is wrong.

Comment: @user1283693 You need to import it like you did with `run`: `from fabric.api import run, env, sudo`

Comment: If the "syntax" were wrong you would get a `SyntaxError` from Python :)

Comment: Yes that works!  pty=True and import sudo solved my problem.  Thanks.

Comment: @ibash When someone solved your problem, you can mark their answer as accepted by clicking the check mark next to it. You can also vote up as many answers as you want (on any question) by clicking the arrows. Both of those things reward people who help you. I linked to a FAQ question about it in a comment on your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `cd` is a shell builtin command and not an actual program that can be run with `sudo`.  You were on the right track with `with cd(...):`.  Try something like:

```
with cd('/my/dir'):
    sudo('ls')
```

I *think* that will work, though admittedly I have not yet tried it myself.  That's because the way the `cd` context manager works is to prepend `cd <dirname> &&` to any command run with `run()` or `sudo()`.